# Showing the data processing inequality

Tags: probability, statistics, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, jensen-inequality

Let $X \sim P_\theta$ for some distribution $P_\theta$ parametrized by $\theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbb R$ and $Y \sim Q(\cdot | X)$ for some distribution $Q$. Assume that $P_\theta$ has a density $p_\theta$, with respect to some ground measure $\mu$ and $Q(\cdot|X)$ has a density $q(\cdot | X)$ with respect to the same $\mu$ for every $X$. Show that the Fisher information of $X$ is at least as large as that of $Y$:

$$\mathbb E\left [ \frac{\int q(Y | X=x) \dot p_\theta(x)dx}{\int q(Y | X=x) p_\theta(x)dx} \right ]^2 \leq \mathbb E\left[\frac{\dot p_\theta(X)}{p_\theta(X)}\right]^2$$

where $\dot p_\theta(x)$ is the first derivative of the density $p_\theta$ with respect to $\theta$.

I'm looking for hints for solving this problem (preferably vague hints that will allow me to still solve the problem myself).

**What I've tried**

The inequality makes some sense to me intuitively but I'm having trouble understanding why it's true. I would usually first try to show a pointwise inequality, but that won't work here since the expectations are over different variables. I also tried expressing the expectations as integrals and switching the order of integration, but that didn't give me any new insights.

My instinct is to apply Cauchy-Schwarz or Jensen's inequality, but I haven't figured out the right way to apply them here.

Comment: I think that the expression you wrote has some issues. E.g. the square should be inside the conditional expectation not after. I hope my solution works. It heavily uses the definition of conditional expectations. If you want you can take lemmas as suggestions :)

Comment: Yes i meant for the square to be inside the expectation, it is a confusion of notation. I will check the solution soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution. Hope it works.

Theorem. Let $X$ a r.v. with probabiliy depending on a parameter $\theta$ and $Y$ s.t. $p(y|x)$ does not depend on $\theta$. Than:

$$I(X)\ge I(Y)$$

where $I$ is the Fisher information.

I remove in the following the $\theta$ indexes in order to simplify notation. For the moment I leave out some details I may add later if I do not find errors or if some reader asks.

LEMMA 1:

$$ I(X)=Var\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} log \ p(X)\right)$$

This is true by definition of Fisher information. q.e.d.

LEMMA 2:

$$Var(E(X|Y))\le Var(X)$$

This is true by the conditional variance decomposition. q.e.d.

LEMMA 3:

$$E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} log \ p(X)|Y\right]= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ log \ p(Y)$$

Let's evaluate $E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} log \ p(X)|Y=y\right]$ for a certain $y$. This is equal to:

$\int_X dx \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} log \ p(x) p(x|y)=$

Now we use Bayes, expand log derivatives and simplify:

$=\int_X dx \frac{\dot p(x)}{p(x)} p(y|x) \frac{p(x)}{p(y)}=\frac{1}{p(y)} \int_X dx \dot p(x)p(y|x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} log p(y)$

q.e.d.

Now combining LEMMA 1, 2 and 3 we get our theorem:

$I(Y)=Var(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ log \ p(Y)) = Var (E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} log \ p(X)|Y\right])\le Var(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} log \ p(X))=I(X)$

The big part is lemma 3.